# Error related to caption style

Tags: errors, captions

I am using a template and got the following error that seems be related to caption.sty:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.78 \newsavebox
                {\as@captionbox}
?
```

Could anyone please help me to solve this error?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: Package `caption` is very often used without problems. So without knowing anything about the template, without [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) and maybe also without version information from the `log` file, you should not expect any help.

Comment: Sorry but as long as you dont provide any code, how are we suppose to help?

Comment: the only occurrence of that line in texlive 2023 is `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption_1995-04-05.sty`  why are you using a frozen legacy 1995 version of the caption package?

Comment: "new" as in less than 30 years old, you mean:-)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz sometimes a crystal ball is all you need

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your crystal ball is better than mine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only occurrence of that line in texlive 2023 is

`/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption_1995-04-05.sty`

There is really no reason to be using a frozen legacy 1995 version of the caption package in 2024.